# How to read a huge string (10000 chars) via cin in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm doing [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/morgan-and-a-string) problem on HackerRank. The solution works as intended, but the test cases that they are giving include strings with more than 10k characters, and all of those aren't being read properly using getline() or cin. What should I do?

My bad, first time posting here.
Only the first 4094 characters are being read.

I'm taking my input like this,

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    getline(cin, strA[i]);
    getline(cin, strB[i]);
}
```

Full code: http://codepad.org/YzR1CMVK

Comment: Could you provide your code to see which cases you're not contemplating :)?

Comment: Please show the code that is not working

Comment: "What should I do?", Use a debugger? :-)

Comment: You will need to provide more information on what you mean by "aren't being read properly". What are you observing and what are you expecting? Please provide an [MCVE] to help us better understand your question.

Comment: 10K hardly qualifies as "huge" these days. Also post your code as people are saying: This is really important. Is `str.max_size()` sufficiently large?

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in there. As François pointed out, a *minimal, **complete*** example is best. This is missing a *lot*. For questions of this sort something self-contained that can be put into a service like [Codepad](http://codepad.org) for testing is best.

Comment: Thanks for the update to the question, but you also need to show how `strA` and `strB` are defined.

Comment: `strA[i].erase(0, 1);` this is... opposite of efficient. This code would work better with iterator instead of indices. Or pointers. Or independent counters for every string. That way you would not need to erase from the beginning from container not suited for that.